# Is it possible to convert svg path with stroke to svg path without any styles and properties?

Tags: javascript, svg

I use svg path with

```
style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 10; stroke-linecap: round; fill: none;"
```

that allows me not to close svg path and it will have particular stroke width and shape.

But I need to use pure svg path without any properties or styles and get the same result.
Is there're any algorithms to achieve it?

Here is an [input svg](http://jsfiddle.net/j5k2ng34/1/).

An output should looks like

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="500" height="500" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="path-data"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: "pure svg path without any properties" you mean with only `<path/>` ? that's a weird requirement, and you won't be able to produce anything from it no. Ah or you mean you're ok to get the `d` attribute, but want the same result as stroke-width=10 but only with the default fill ?

Comment: That's correct! Updated question description.

Comment: Then it's not trivial to produce such a path programmatically, stroking can be tricky.